# Fall into/within/under categories

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between "fall into/fall within/fall under several categories"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fall into a category vs. fall under a category](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24658/fall-into-a-category-vs-fall-under-a-category)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for being such an arrogant! It isn't the same question as I needed also to know the meaning of fall within categories. I'm out of here